# (React) Button click not working with Beautiful DnD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using Beautiful-DnD for a project where if certain items are dragged and dropped into different columns, with a button click, it will reroute the user to a different page. I am having trouble where the button does not execute it's onClick function. I believe this is due to the Beautiful-DnD code I am using, but I can't determine why. Here is my parent component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DragNDrop from './DragNDrop.js';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


export default function Home() {

    const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);

    const characteristics = [
        { id: "geo", content: 'Geopolitical' },
        { id: "dog", content: 'Dog Loving' },
        { id: "python", content: 'Python' },
        { id: "react", content: 'React ' }
    ];

    const starterColumns = {
        "1": {
            name: 'characteristics',
            items: characteristics
            },
        "2": {
            name: '2',
            items: []
        }
    }

    const reRoute = () => {
        if (columns['2']['items'] == "Geopolitical") {
            return (
                <h2><Link to={{
                    pathname: `/cia`}}
                    >See Gallery of Old Logos</Link></h2>
            )
        }
    }     

    useEffect(() => {
        setColumns(starterColumns)
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            <DragNDrop columns = {columns} setColumns = {setColumns}/>
            <button onClick={e => reRoute(), console.log}>Hello</button>               
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the Beautiful-DnD component (DragNDrop component)

```
import React from 'react';
import Board from './Board.js';
import Card from './Card.js';
import { DndProvider } from 'react-dnd';
import Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import '../styles/Home.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';


const characteristics = [
    { id: "geo", content: 'Geopolitical' },
    { id: "dog", content: 'Dog Loving' },
    { id: "python", content: 'Python' },
    { id: "react", content: 'React ' }
];


const starterColumns = {
    "1": {
        name: 'I am',
        items: characteristics
        },
    "2": {
        name: 'and I develop with',
        items: []
    }
}

const onDragEnd = (result, columns, setColumns) => {
    if (!result.destination) return;
    const { source, destination } = result;
    if (source.droppableId !== destination.droppableId) {
        const sourceColumn = columns[source.droppableId];
        const destColumn = columns[destination.droppableId];
        const sourceItems = [...sourceColumn.items];
        const destItems = [...destColumn.items];
        const [removed] = sourceItems.splice(source.index, 1);
        destItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
        setColumns({
            ...columns,
            [source.droppableId]: {
                ...sourceColumn,
                items: sourceItems
            },
            [destination.droppableId]: {
                ...destColumn,
                items: destItems
            }})
    } else {
        const column = columns[source.droppableId];
        const copiedItems = [...column.items]
        const [removed] = copiedItems.splice(source.index, 1);
        copiedItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
        setColumns({
            ...columns,
            [source.droppableId]: {
                ...column,
                items: copiedItems
            }
        })
    }
};


export default function DragNDrop (props) {


    return (
        <div style={{displey: 'flex', justifyContent:'center', height: '100%'}}>
            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={result => onDragEnd(result, props.columns, props.setColumns)}>
                {Object.entries(props.columns).map(([id, column]) => {
                    return (
                        <div stle={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: ' center', height: '100%'}}>                           <h2>{column.name}</h2>
                            <Droppable droppableId={id} key={id}>
                                {(provided, snapshot) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div
                                            {...provided.droppableProps}
                                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                                            // for changing what happens when something is being dragged
                                            style={{
                                                background: snapshot.isDraggingOver ? 'lightblue' : 'lightgrey',
                                                padding: 4,
                                                width: 250,
                                                minHeight: 500
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {column.items.map((item, index) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <Draggable key={item.id} draggableId={item.id} index={index}>
                                                        {(provided, snapshot) => {
                                                            return (
                                                                <div ref={provided.innerRef}
                                                                {...provided.draggableProps}
                                                                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                                                style={{
                                                                    userSelect: 'none',
                                                                    padding: 16,
                                                                    margin: '0 0 8px 0',
                                                                    minHeight: '50px',
                                                                    backgroundColor: snapshot. isDragging ? ' #263B4A' : '#456C86',
                                                                    color: 'white',
                                                                    ...provided.draggableProps.style
                                                                }}
                                                                >
                                                                {item.content}
                                                                </div> 
                                                            )}}
                                                    </Draggable>
                                                )})}
                                            {provided.placeholder}    
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                }}
                            </Droppable>

                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </DragDropContext>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the intention that when `reRoute` executes that navigation occurs? `onClick` doesn't really have a return type so returning a JSX element to the `onClick` handler of a button wouldn't have the effect you are looking for. If you want navigation to change, you could use `https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history` method push to execute a redirect.

Comment: It does trigger it probably but does not get into the scope of if statement.